# vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html reports/ not including html assets when generating report files - only shows plain text and links

Tags: php, phpunit

When I run `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html reports/` it generates all of the report html files but the assets are not loading for css files.

Therefore all I am getting is plain text and links for my reports. Do these assets have to be added manually?

[image: Here is an image of what my report looks like in one of my files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my report was failing due to the following error:

```
Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 225280 bytes) in /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-api/web-app/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template/src/Template.php on line 90
```

The fix was adding `-d memory_limit=-1` when running the report so the memory does not get exhausted.

The final command looks like this

```
XDEBUG_MODE=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit -d memory_limit=-1  --coverage-html reports/ tests/Unit
```

Now it finishes the html report generation including the assets